# How a list can enter into a python dataframe's cell?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have some dataframes (df, tmp_df and final_df) and I want to enter two columns of tmp_df into two differenrt cells of final_df as list type. My code and dataframes are presented as follow. However, the loop part is not working correctly. The other questions in stackoverflow or other websites, answer this question if there is an available dictionary for the lists from the beginning of the program. But here, the tmp_df dataframe changes during the for loop and at each iteration suitable prices are calculated. Also, the most related data are founded and they must locate as a realted cell of final_df.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    tmp_df = df[df['Type'] == True]
    cnt = 0
    for c in tmp_df['Category']:
        #################
        # Apply some calculations and call different methods to do some changes on Price column of tmp_df.
        #################
        final_df.at[cnt,'Data'] = list(set(tmp_sub['Data']))
        final_df ['Category'], final_df['Acceptable'], final_df['Rank'],final_df['Price'] = \
        tmp_df['Rank'], list(tmp_sub['Price'])
        cnt +=1



df:

| Data    | Category | Acceptable | Rank | Price |
| ------- | -------- | ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| 30275   | A        | Yes        |  1   | 52787 |
| 35881   | C        | No         |  2   | 14804 |
| 28129   | C        | Yes        |  3   | 180543|
| 30274   | D        | No         |  2   | 8066  |
| 30351   | D        | Yes        |  3   | 273478|
| 35886   | A        | Yes        |  2   | 10808 |
| 39900   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 21893 |
| 35887   | A        | No         |  2   | 2244  |
| 35883   | A        | Yes        |  1   | 10066 |
| 35856   | D        | Yes        |  3   | 19011 |
| 35986   | C        | No         |  2   | 6895  |
| 30350   | D        | No         |  3   | 5243  |
| 28129   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 112859|
| 31571   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 20701 |

tmp_df:

| Data    | Category | Acceptable | Rank | Price |
| ------- | -------- | ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| 30275   | A        | Yes        |  1   | 52787 |
| 38129   | C        | Yes        |  3   | 180543|
| 30351   | D        | Yes        |  3   | 273478|
| 35886   | A        | Yes        |  2   | 10808 |
| 39900   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 21893 |
| 35883   | A        | Yes        |  1   | 10066 |
| 35856   | D        | Yes        |  3   | 19011 |
| 28129   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 112859|
| 31571   | C        | Yes        |  1   | 20701 |

The prices in the final dataframe (final_df) are changed because of the calculations over the tmp_df. Now, what should I do if I want the following result?

final_df:

| Data                      | Category | Acceptable | Rank | Price |
| -------                   | -------- | ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| [30275,35886,35883]       | A        | Yes        | [1,2]| 195543|
| [28129,39900,38129,31571] | C        | Yes        | [1,3]| 210089|
| [30351,35856]             | D        | Yes        |   3  | 113859|
```

Comment: How is count `Price` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate `list` and for `Price` another aggregation function, e.g. `sum`, `mean`...:

```
#generate custom function for Price
def func(x):
    
    return x.sum()

d = {'Data':list,'Rank':lambda x: list(set(x)), 'Price':func}
final_df = (tmp_df.groupby(['Category','Acceptable'],as_index=False)
                  .agg(d)
                  .reindex(tmp_df.columns, axis=1))
```

---

```
d = {'Data':list,'Rank':lambda x: list(set(x)), 'Price':'max'}
final_df = (tmp_df.groupby(['Category','Acceptable'],as_index=False)
                  .agg(d)
                  .reindex(tmp_df.columns, axis=1))

print (final_df)
                           Data Category Acceptable    Rank   Price
0         [30275, 35886, 35883]        A        Yes  [1, 2]   52787
1  [38129, 39900, 28129, 31571]        C        Yes  [1, 3]  180543
2                [30351, 35856]        D        Yes     [3]  273478
```

---

Solution with custom function:

```
def func1(x):
    return x.sum()


def f(x):

    a = list(x['Data'])
    b = list(set(x['Rank']))
    c = func1(x['Price'])
    
    return pd.Series({'Data':a,'Rank':b,'Price':c})


final_df = (tmp_df.groupby(['Category','Acceptable'])
                  .apply(f)
                  .reset_index()
                  .reindex(tmp_df.columns, axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks. But as you see the Price column is not just provided by `sum` or `mean`. I have used a couple of functions for different situations. So, I cannot use aggregation functions here.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There are other columns as well for this dataframe, but I did not use them because the question would be crowded. I have applied different changes to the other columns as well. I want just to add the list of `Data` and `Rank` to the related cells of each row.

Comment: @V.Nouri - First dont use loops, here is not necessary. Then what means `I have used a couple of functions for different situation` ? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @V.Nouri - `I have applied different changes to the other columns as well.` so it means defindex it in function `f` or in dictionary `d`, need each column which is processing.

Comment: @ jezrael - For instance I send the dataframe to a function and check if the `Rank` and `Price` in a class (based on other columns), then add a constant amount to the price, otherwise I would add a negative sign of the amount to the price. Also, I apply a kind of classification on the `Rank` and some other features and return them for changing the `Price` column. I hope this could be helpful for you.

Comment: @V.Nouri - Hmmm, then is for you necessary use function `f` and change it like you need.

Comment: @V.Nouri - Becuase only there is possible create `Price` depends of another columns values.

Comment: @ jezrael - Yes, exactly. This is the big problem and I cannot use `df.query` or `df.agg` and other powerful features like these. I need a way just to copy the lists into the specific cells.

Comment: @V.Nouri - yes, `groupby.apply` is solution for you. It is alternative for your loops, which is necessary avoid in pandas.

Comment: @ jezrael - Can you write the code for me?
Because I am not sure about this. Can `groupby.apply` add  the list of `Data` or `Rank` into the cells as well?

Comment: @V.Nouri - It is already written in answer. Last paragraph.

Comment: @ jezrael - oh, Sorry. Yes, I forgot it!!
But how can I call my functions in between `groupby.apply`?

Comment: @V.Nouri - `how can I call my functions` ? Not understand. Which function?

Comment: @ jezrael - as I mentioned I `For instance I send the dataframe to a function and check if the Rank and Price in a class (based on other columns) hen add a constant amount to the price`. So I need to use some functions to do some changes on `Price ` and `Rank` columns in the dataframe and finally add them into the `final_df `. how can I call those functions when I am using the `groupby.apply`?

Comment: @ jezrael -  I know `apply(f)` is for one function but can I use other functions as well?

Comment: @V.Nouri - Answer is edited. You can call function in another function.

Comment: @ jezrael - Thanks.